# How to give an id to a newly created div inside parent div With design Mode on

Tags: javascript, php, html

As if we make a div element with it `contenteditable="true"` and then when if this is seen in console then

1st. In console there is simple a div tag.

```
<div id="typbody" contenteditable="true" style="width:100%; height:200px; border:1px solid #ccc; "></div>
```

2nd. If I press enter in div tag then in console it is written `<div><br></div>`!

and If I write anything in that the it is also written inside `<div>`.

so my question is:

1) Is there any way to give these newly created `div` tag an id ?
2) Is there also any way to give them different ids or class to all new `div`'s?

Do I have to learn any other language other than `javascript` or `php`?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: What do you mean under "design Mode on" ?

Comment: `<html>
<head><title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="typbody" contenteditable="true" style="width:100%; height:200px; border:1px solid #ccc; "></div>

</body>
</html>` just this much!

Comment: If you trying to manually change id of element that was logged in console, right click on it with mouse, and then choose "Reveal in Elements panel" then click again and choose "Add attribute" or "Edit attribute". (in *Google Chrome*, and it might be similar in other browsers too)

Comment: But, if you creating this "new div elements" with javascript, why not, simply add id attribute while creating it?

Comment: First please try these code in google. So actually as i mentioned above that when `Enter` is pressed then a new tag is created like in `Iframe` so i want to give Id to those tags automatically!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *"Is there is any way to give these newly created `div` tag an id ?"*
2. *"Is there is also any way to give them different ids or class to all new div's?"*

#### Yes, there is!

Look at  [MutationObserver MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver),
and [DOM MutationObserver – reacting to DOM changes without killing browser performance.](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)

[***Demonstration with JS***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/tH3ME/5/)

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var target = document.getElementById("typbody"),
        config = {
            childList: true,
        },
        eCollection = [],
        i = 0,
        id = target.id + "_",

        observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                if (mutation.addedNodes) {
                    [].forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function (node) {
                        if (node.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "div") {
                            var index = eCollection.indexOf(node.nextSibling);
                            node.id = id + i++;
                            eCollection.push(node);
                            if (node.nextSibling && index > -1) {
                                node.id = node.nextSibling.id;
                                for (var j = index; j < eCollection.length - 1; j++) {
                                    eCollection[j].id = id + (+eCollection[j].id.substr(id.length) + 1);
                                }
                            }
                            eCollection.sort(sortC);
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (mutation.removedNodes) {
                    [].forEach.call(mutation.removedNodes, function (node) {
                        if (node.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "div") {
                            var index = eCollection.indexOf(node);
                            eCollection.splice(index, 1);
                            for (var j = index; j < eCollection.length; j++) {
                                eCollection[j].id = id + (eCollection[j].id.substr(id.length) - 1);
                            }
                            i--;
                            eCollection.sort(sortC);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    observer.observe(target, config);

    function sortC(a, b) {
        return a.id.substr(id.length) - b.id.substr(id.length);
    }
}());
```

But why you want such behavior?
If you want to add some style to those elements, why not simply use css:

[***Demo with CSS***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/emb9K/)

```
#typbody > div:nth-child(odd) {
    color: green;
}
#typbody > div:nth-child(even) {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the id when you create it. If you want it to be dynamic, just make the id variable dynamic.

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
var item = document.createElement('div');
item.id = whatever;
frag.appendChild(item);
```

and then insert the frag into your DOM wherever you want. For instance, after an element 'foo':

```
foo.parentNode.insertBefore(frag, foo.nextSibling);
```